# Difference Between (void *)pointer and &pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, void, memory-address

I'm learning C using [LCTHW](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/) and I came across some pointer stuff that interested me, so I found [this](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/16/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers/). While going through it, I found this code:

```
void *vptr; // declare as a void pointer type
int val = 1;
int *iptr;

// void type can hold any pointer type or reference
iptr = &val;
vptr = iptr;
printf("iptr=%p, vptr=%p\n", (void *)iptr, (void *)vptr);
```

Running that gives me something like this:

```
iptr=0x7fffa97a8464, vptr=0x7fffa97a8464
```

Obviously, the memory addresses would be the same, so C prints out the same thing for both of them. However, when experimenting with the code and putting in, instead of the last line:

```
printf("iptr=%p, vptr=%p\n", &iptr, &vptr);
```

I get this:

```
iptr=0x7fff61a21ee0, vptr=0x7fff61a21ed8
```

I get two different memory addresses printed out, which shouldn't be happening. First question: If the ampersand here means "address of," as Dennis says in the post, then why do the two lines of code output two different things? Second question: Since the two lines of code output two different things, obviously (void *)pointer must mean something different than &pointer. What is the difference between those two things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(void*)ptr` casts `ptr` to a void pointer without altering its value. `&ptr`, on the other hand, yields *the address of the pointer itself*. In other words, `&ptr` is a pointer to a pointer. `iptr` and `vptr` are different objects and as such they have different addresses.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that `(void *)ptr` really means "address of," and that `&ptr` doesn't really mean that, and Dennis is wrong?

Comment: Well, actually, I guess Dennis would be right, since `&ptr` means "address of pointer"

Comment: `&` is the address-of operator. `&ptr` takes the address of the pointer. If you want the address of the pointed-to object, both `(void*)ptr` and `ptr` will give you that.

Comment: Would `printf("iptr=%p, vptr=%p\n", iptr, vptr);` be valid?

Comment: Yes. That would print the addresses of the pointed-to objects (the address of `val` in this case).

Comment: `(void *)ptr` does not mean 'address of'; it means 'convert the value stored in `ptr` to a `void *`. In the case of `iptr`, it means convert the value stored in `iptr` to a `void *` (which is usually a no-op these days, but I learned C on machines where, had there been `void *`, the bit pattern of the value of a `void *` address for a memory location would have been different from the `int *` address for the same memory location ). `&iptr` generates the address of an `int` pointer, or an `int **`; it should be cast with `(void *)&iptr` in the call to `printf()` since `%p` expects a `void *`.

Answer (score 4):

`(void *)pointer` casts `pointer` to a pointer-to-`void`—that is, a pointer to anything. `&pointer`, on the other hand, takes the address of the variable (not that to which it points), so if `pointer` was of type `char *`, the type of `&pointer` would be `char **`. The reason this:

```
printf("iptr=%p, vptr=%p\n", &iptr, &vptr);
```

prints two different values is because though `iptr` and `vptr` contain the same value (they point to the same thing), they are two different variables, and so the variables themselves are distinct.